# aws cdk ignores assume role statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I've try to recreate cloudfront stack with lambda.
got an error:

```
The function execution role must be assumable with edgelambda.amazonaws.com as well as lambda.amazonaws.com principals. Update the IAM role and try again
```

[image]

However the principal is assumed:

[image]

Does generated cloudformation output of two set of "assumedRole" actions
is correct?

[image]

The code seems working for me, the change that was made is that I deleted local cdk.out.

Answer (score 0):

Cured by deploying the same stack with the another name.